# How to find Quartile 3 of a linked list given that you can only iterate through the list once

Tags: linked-list

Similar to question asked here ([How to find the quartiles in the linked list with only one iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65918154/how-to-find-the-quartiles-in-the-linked-list-with-only-one-iteration)).

I can easily find Quartile 1 using the method specified in the above post, however, quartile 3 is always wrong for me. Sometimes it is off by 1, and others 2 or more. I am moving the Quartile 3 pointer by 3 every iteration, is this correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: The exact definition of a quartile becomes debatable when the list size is not a multiple of 4. You should define what exactly a correct quartile 3 is in those cases. Also provide the code you have a problem with.

Comment: The definition of quartiles that I am working with is as follows: Order your data set from lowest to highest values
Find the median. This is the second quartile Q2.
At Q2 split the ordered data set into two halves.
The lower quartile Q1 is the median of the lower half of the data.
The upper quartile Q3 is the median of the upper half of the data.

Comment: What if the list is even in size, then is Q2 the average of the two middle values?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, the average also goes for Q1 and Q3 if their respective halves are of even size

Comment: So when the list spits, do these two middle nodes each go to each half list? If so, then what happens when the original list is odd, and the median is at one node: where does that node go to? To avoid a long discussion, can you update your question and give examples for several cases, and include your code with example input, and explain how it gives a result that is wrong (expected output, output you get instead)?

Comment: The middle 2 nodes go to their respective sides, yes. So the node to the left of the median will go to the left side, and the node to the right of the median will go to the right

Comment: So what when the list is odd? Where does the median node go to?

Comment: It is not moved, it is the median.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that the node references should make a step forward depending on the number of the iteration modulo 4:

The node reference for q1 should only move once in every 4 iterations, while the q2 node reference should step forward once every 2 iterations, and finally the q3 reference should step forward 3 out of 4 iterations.

Once the iterations are completed, it has to be decided whether the q* nodes are exactly on the corresponding median, or the average with its successor node should be taken. Again, this is determined by the size of the list modulo 4.

Here is a little implementation in JavaScript:

```js
function makeList(arr) {
    return arr.reduceRight((next, val) => ({ next, val }), null);
}

function* fromList(head) {
    while (head) {
        yield head.val;
        head = head.next;
    }
}

function getMedians(head) {
    if (head == null || head.next == null) return; // Need at least 2 values

    let node1 = head, 
        node2 = head, 
        node3 = head.next,
        node4 = node3.next,
        size = 2;
    
    while (node4) {
        if (size % 4 == 1) node1 = node1.next;
        if (size % 2 == 0) node2 = node2.next;
        if (size % 4 != 3) node3 = node3.next;
        node4 = node4.next;
        size++;
    }
    return [
        size % 4 < 2 ? (node1.val + node1.next.val) / 2 : node1.val,
        size % 2 < 1 ? (node2.val + node2.next.val) / 2 : node2.val, 
        size % 4 < 2 ? (node3.val + node3.next.val) / 2 : node3.val,
    ];
}

// Example run
let head = makeList([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]);
console.log("list", ...fromList(head));
let [q1, q2, q3] = getMedians(head);
console.log("q1, q2, q3 => ", q1, q2, q3);
```